# how does a BSWM module(as a mode manager) receive a request from an application SWC (as an user mode) to change mode in AUTOSAR?

Tags: autosar

In my architecture there is an ASWC(as the mode user) requesting to change the mode from BSWM module(as the mode manger) via a sender-receiver port and the BSWM is supposed to send the changed mode via a mode switch port in response. I have made sender-receiver and mode switch ports and interfaces in my ASWC  and added The ASWC descriptions to the configuration tool(EB Tresos) as well. While configuring, I made an BswMModeRequestPortset and added required arbitration rules and set BswMRequestProcessing to BSWM_IMMEDIATE . After Generating, As the attached picture shows, I expected that the configuration tool generated required code checking arbitration rules (ModeArbitration() in the picture) and issued the related action via the mode switch port to the mode users in the mode arbitration runnable. But, what it was generated was a blanked runnable body as if the user is expected to fill it by hand.
If the user must typically fill the runnable body, what API must be used ??
thanks for your answers in advance. [image]

Comment: Can you please provide the respective (obfuscated) ECUC file content and generated code?
I am not really getting your question.
The generated code for your BswM rules is in the generated code for the BswM.
The code for the Runnable for sure you have to implement yourself.
How should the generator even know your custom logic?